# MSBuild condition for whether the entry assembly is being compiled

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

My goal is to add another PackageReference automatically to any "entry" assembly. Generally it's the one with a Main() defined, but not any class libraries.

I tried adding something like this to my Directory.Build.props:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(IS_THE_ENTRY_ASSEMBLY)' == 'true' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="..." />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I could not find any MSBuild property that would tell me if an assembly was an entry assembly, so another condition that would work is "Does this assembly reference the package Serilog.Sinks.File?". To do that, I tried various forms like this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '%(PackageReference.Include)' == 'Serilog.Sinks.File' ">
<ItemGroup Condition=" '%(PackageReference)' == 'Serilog.Sinks.File' ">
<ItemGroup Condition=" '@(PackageReference)' == 'Serilog.Sinks.File' ">
```

But, I can't seem to find the right syntax for doing this, either.

Either method of solving this would be welcome.

Comment: Directory.Build.props is for common properties. In this case you want to apply property to specific project. Than why not to write this line in required project?

Comment: @JL0PD I could (and did, to get past this for now), but I want to learn if there’s a way to do this automatically in one place for many projects in a solution. The actual logic I need also checks for an environment variable, and it would be nice to avoid duplicating it everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's four possibilities on how code may be compiled: `exe`, `winexe`, `library`, `module` (can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019#list-of-common-properties-and-parameters)). Is set via `<OutputType>` in project file.

- `exe` usable for console application. May be used for windowed application, but on launch console window is opened
- `winexe` usable for windowed application. No console created
- `library` for libraries. Cannot be ran directly
- `module` not sure how to use it

First 2 requires `Main` function to be able to run, so we can check if `OutputType` is set to one of them

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(OutputType)' == 'exe' or '$(OutputType)' == 'winexe'">
    <!-- only be applied to runnable projects -->
    <ProjectReference Include="...">
</ItemGroup>
```

If `OutputType` is not set in project file - defaults to `Library`

Not sure whether string comparison will be case-sensitive or insensitive